# Uncaught ReferenceError: checkin is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem with js function on button click.

```html
<button class="checkin_button btn-block" onclick="checkin(345)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Check In</button>
```

My jQuery function is:

```js
var CheckIn;
$(document).ready(function() {
  CheckIn = function checkin(id) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: {
        action: 'foody_checkin',
        'restaurant' = id,
      },
      beforeSend: function() {},
      success: function() {}
    });
  }
});
```

But its not working.

Comment: @AlivetoDie not works

Comment: Put `checkin()` outside of Jquery ready function.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checkin(345)` is  a function, so do like below:-

```
function checkin(id){
   var ajaxurl = "abc.com" //an example that you have to define ajaxurl before using it
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : ajaxurl, // now you can use ajaxurl happily
        data : {
            action : 'foody_checkin',
            'restaurant': id,  // : needed instead of =
        },
        beforeSend : function(){},
        success : function(){}
    });
}
```

***Notes:-***

1.Please take care of comments written inside quote.

2.Also check that jQuery library added before you script code

Comment: ajaxurl works for other ajax calls..but problem is here. used : needed instead of =

Comment: since it a function so either define `ajaxurl` inside function or directly put url there instead of `ajaxurl`

Answer (score 0):

Try to using data-id method
html

```
<button class="checkin_button btn-block" data-id='345'><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Check In</button>
```

jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkin_button', function () {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(id);
  // write your ajax below
});
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/nuxtw2ft/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **this** keyword to assign value to the var declared. Call the same on click of button.

Also assign value to ajaxurl as AlivetoDie stated in his answer.

You can run the code snippet below and verify.

```js
var CheckIn;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ajaxurl="yourservice.com"
  this.CheckIn = function checkin(id) {
    console.log("CheckIn function called on click");
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: {
        action: 'foody_checkin',
        'restaurant': id,
      },
      beforeSend: function() {},
      success: function() {}
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="checkin_button btn-block" onclick="CheckIn(345)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Check In</button>
```

Hope this helps!